# Opposite of Ctrl + C in command prompt forJupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, jupyter

So when I start my enviroment from anaconda, and right click the play button to open for Jupyter Notebook. It opens up Brackets, and then when I click "Live Preview". It opens up a google chrome browser, first with an address from buckets like this

file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Brackets/www/LiveDevelopment/launch.html

Then:
http://localhost:8891/tree?token=6cb728c78bea88a8727007dfd89e5e5a8ec0c8ed538d1b01

1. Sometimes within the command prompt Ill use Ctrl + C to copy, but its
   actually a shortcut to terminate the kernal. My question is from the
   command prompt, can I undo Ctrl + C, what is the command in there I
   can restart the kernel?

Some secondary questions are:

1. How can I make brackets not the ddefault opener for Conda > Jupyter
   Notebook.
2. How can I make Brackets open up Firefox?
3. How can I use these links to open up in a separate Firefox browser
   for Jupyter Notebook without Bracket.?
4. How do I copy cells in the command prompt?
5. How do you repeat the previous line in the command prompt?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. People will be happy to help. Split your questions and ask multiple questions.

Comment: Thank you, do you want me to make moltiple topics? I didnt want to spam as this being my first post(s). I'd be enthused if I could just get the first question answered.